# Pass selected checkbox value to Servlet/JSP page using `href` attribute

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, servlets

In my scenario, Checkboxes are dynamically created when the JSP page is loaded. The JSP page contains multiple `href` attributes, some redirecting to the JSP and some redirect to the Servlet.

I want to send the name of selected checkbox to the JSP or Servlet.

What are the possible options to do this?

[my jsp page](http://pastebin.com/5hdgnppz)

Comment: I'd suggest providing example code fragments laying out the structure of what you're aiming for, and the specific area where you're struggling. You're more likely to get a quality response if you make digesting the question easier.

Comment: Grammar and formatting cleanup to improve readability, in order to assist in getting a quality answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that easy using javascript as the user select checkbox

1. **option 1**

you fire a request using ajax (XMLHttpRequest)that will have name and value of the checkbox (my way of doing it)

2. **option 2**

create on the fly with javascript a new input with name of the selected checkbox and submit to jsp

a more of example on option 2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="description" content="Demo project">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style type="text/css"></style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
function checkBoxSubit(e) {
    var form=document.createElement('form');
    form.style.display = 'none';
    var input=document.createElement('input');
    input.name="myname";
    input.type="checkbox";
    input.value=e.value;
    console.log(input);
    form.action='myservlet.jsp';
    form.method='post';
    form.appendChild(input);
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
 </script>
<input type="checkbox" onmousedown="checkBoxSubit(this);" name="check" value="555">
<input type="checkbox" onmousedown="checkBoxSubit(this);" name="check" value="252">
<input type="checkbox" onmousedown="checkBoxSubit(this);" name="check" value="258">
<input type="checkbox" onmousedown="checkBoxSubit(this);" name="check" value="660">
<input type="checkbox" onmousedown="checkBoxSubit(this);" name="check" value="784">


    </body>
 </html>
```